# RStudio on Amazon EMR cluster

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-emr

I'm new at using Amazon web services and i'm trying to build a cluster on it to run my mapreduce job.
I created an AWS account, a bucket "xxxx" and a keypair "rania". And i followed this post https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/big-data/statistical-analysis-with-open-source-r-and-rstudio-on-amazon-emr/
to create the cluster.
I ran this code in my ubunto console:

```
bucket="<xxxx>"
region="<eu-west-1>"
keypair="<rania>"

aws emr create-cluster --name emR-example \
--ami-version 3.2.1 \
--region $eu-west-1 \
--ec2-attributes KeyName=$rania \
--no-auto-terminate \
--instance-groups \
InstanceGroupType=MASTER,InstanceCount=1,InstanceType=m1.large \
InstanceGroupType=CORE,InstanceCount=2,InstanceType=m1.large \
--bootstrap-actions \
Name=emR_bootstrap,\
Path="s3://$xxxx/emR_bootstrap.sh",\
Args=[--rstudio,--rhdfs,--plyrmr,--rexamples] \
--steps \
Name=HDFS_tmp_permission,\
Jar="s3://elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar",\
Args="s3://$xxxx/hdfs_permission.sh"
```

but this error appears :

```
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: argument --region: expected one argument
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a dollar sign in the region line that shouldn't be there

Comment: this kind of short statement only suits in comment.